# Using vue-youtube package the player is not getting initialized in iOS after switching orientation

Tags: ios, vue.js, google-chrome, youtube-api, screen-orientation

I am trying to run a youtube video using vue-youtube package.

The video plays fine in portrait and landscape mode in all Android/Mac/Windows in all browsers.

However when you switch between portrait to Landscape, the player is not getting initialized in iOS chrome + Safari browsers.

Below is the snippet of the code which we are using :

**vue.js**

```js
computed: {
  player() {
    return this.$refs.youtube.player;
  },
}
```

And the Html code is :

```html
<youtube
  id="youtube"
  :video-id="embedId"
  ref="youtube"
  :player-vars="playerVars"
  disablepictureinpicture
  controlslist="nodownload"
  fitParent
  muted
  @ready="onReady"
  @cued="cued"
  @playing="playing"
  @paused="paused">
</youtube>
```